# Jquery input value as selector to append content. Then use input value as appended content

Tags: jquery, html, input, selector

I have two columns. I want to choose column 1 column 2 or both to append content to, using checkboxes. So, I think I need to use the "value" attribute of the checkbox as a $selector.

Then I need to append two divs to that selector. One, nested inside the other.

The first div should have the class="item" plus the class="written in the second text input"
And in the second div the *htmlcontent* should be the content written in the first input.

Thank you.

```
<div id="container">    
<div class="a">
    <div class="name">Column 1</div>    
    <div class="one">
      <div class="item eagle">
         <div class="cont">Content for 1A</div>
      </div> 
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="b">
    <div class="name">Column 2</div>    
    <div class="two">
      <div class="item lion">
        <div class="cont">content for 2A</div>
      </div> 
    </div>    
</div>    
</div>


<form id="createitems">
  <input id="content" name="content" type="text" placeholder="Content text here">
  <input id="content2" name="content2" type="text" placeholder="Animal class here">
    
  <input id="colchoice" name="column" type="checkbox" value="one">
  <label for="colchoice">One</label>
    
  <input id="colchoice2" name="column" type="checkbox" value="two">
  <label for="colchoice2">Two</label>

  <button id="create" form="createitems" type="button">Create</button>
</form>


$("#create").click(function(){

var check = $("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
var col = $('input[name="column"]:checked').val();

if (check == true){
    
    $( col ).append("<div class="item"><div class="cont"></div></div>");
    $(".cont").html($("content").val());
    
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FYPs89/zmmoojL4/)

Comment: Can you explain more clearly ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/robinat130/0cahbs6c/ check this fiddle

Comment: Sample HTML would help explain things better.

Comment: Added the full HTML and corrected a little for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some edits, I think I think I have a fully working solution

Javascript:

```
$("#create").click(function () {

    //Cycles through all checked boxes of name='column'
    $('input[name="column"]:checked').each(function () {
        var outerDiv = $("."+this.value);
        var itemDiv = $('<div/>').addClass("item " + $('#content2').val());
        var contDiv = $('<div/>').addClass("cont").html($("#content").val());

        outerDiv.prepend(itemDiv.prepend(contDiv));

        if (this.value == "one") {
            $('.a').append(outerDiv);
        }

        if (this.value == "two") {
            $('.b').append(outerDiv);
        }
    });

});
```

I also made a change to your CSS to anchor the divs to the top of the parent container (otherwise, if there are uneven amounts of elements in each column, you will get unaligned columns)

```
.a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; //Added this
    width:45%;
}
.b {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; //Added this
    width:45%;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmmoojL4/9/

Comment: Yes, thats pretty much it. But it seems to change it instead of appending a new set of divs.

Comment: you can do something like `$('.a').append("<div>" + $('#content').val() + "</div>");`

Comment: @FYP89 Please see my updated solution, I believe it meets all requirements

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$("#create").click(function () {
$('input[name="column"]:checked').each(function () {
    $('.' + this.value).find('.cont').append($("#content").val());
    $('.' + this.value).find('.cont').addClass($("#content2").val());
});
```

});

[try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/zmmoojL4/10/)

Comment: this will addclass as well, I think your second input do this work